# Magento 2.3 wrong image cache generation

Tags: magento2.3, image, product-page, bug

I have upgraded my Magento EE store from 2.2.7 to 2.3.2. An issue occurred of images not showing on product pages.

I debugged a bit and ran the command "catalog:image:resize" and images appeared. But when I flush catalog images cache from admin, the issue appeared again.

I think the images cache is not generating. The permission for pub/media are also 777.

Also the product images are appearing on category page but not on product page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After intense searching and debugging, issue appeared to be of missing htaccess file in pub/media/ folder. Added the file from magento 2.3.2 git. Because the images cache folders weren't generating due to missing htaccess.

Comment: Make sure .htacess does exist in pub/media